# MySQL query using an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to query a MySQL database using an array but I'm having trouble!

I have a table called clients, I want to be able to select 'name' from all rows whose 'sector' column is equal to $sectorlink.

I then want to put all the names into an array so I can perform my next query: select all rows from another table whose 'client' column is equal to one of the names returned from the first query. I'm doing something wrong because it returns a fatal SQL error. I'm getting confused with all the variables!

$sectorlink and $connection are the only variables that are defined outside of this code

Any suggestions?

```
$query1 = "SELECT name FROM clients WHERE sector = '$sectorlink'";
$clientresult = mysql_query($query1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clientresult)){

foreach($row AS $key => $value){$temp[] = '"'.$value.'"';}
$thelist = implode(",",$temp);

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE client IN ($row) ORDER BY (date) desc";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second query should use `$thelist` not `$row`, and it should be outside of the `while` loop. The `foreach` loop is unnecessary when processing a single row. You can access the name in `$row` with a simple `$row[0]`. Something like this (untested):

```
$query1 = "SELECT name FROM clients WHERE sector = '$sectorlink'";
$clientresult = mysql_query($query1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clientresult)){
    $temp[] = '"'.$row[0].'"';
}

$thelist = implode(",",$temp);
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE client IN ($thelist) ORDER BY (date) desc";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

**Caution:** Please be aware that your code is highly vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). It's fine for testing or internal development but if this code is going to be running the Fort Knox web site you're going to want to fix it up quite a bit. Just an FYI. :-)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.Yeah, I will need to fix the code against injection, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: P.S. You could also do this in a single query with a sub-select: `SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE client IN (SELECT name FROM clients WHERE sector = '$sectorlink') ORDER BY (date) desc`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.  First you have an unnecessary loop there.  Try:

```
while (list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($clientresult)) {

    $temp[] = $name;
}
```

To build your temporary array.

Second, the parts of the `IN` clause are strings, so when you implode, you'll need to enclose each value in quotes:

```
$thelist = "'". implode("','", $temp) . "'";
```

Lastly, in your query you are passing `$row` to the `IN` clause, you should be passing `$thelist`:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE client IN ($thelist) ORDER BY date desc";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

So altogether:

```
$query1 = "SELECT name FROM clients WHERE sector = '$sectorlink'";
$clientresult = mysql_query($query1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while (list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($clientresult)) {

    $temp[] = $name;
}

$thelist = "'". implode("','", $temp) . "'"; 

$query = "SELECT count(*) FROM studies WHERE client IN ($thelist) ORDER BY date desc";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try This:

```
$query1 = "SELECT name FROM clients WHERE sector = '$sectorlink'";
$clientresult = mysql_query($query1, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clientresult)){

$client = $row['name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM studies WHERE client='$client' ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

/* echo results here */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'd be better off doing this in one query with a join:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM `studies` INNER JOIN `clients` on studies.client = clients.name WHERE clients.sector = '$sectorlink' ORDER BY studies.date DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```