# How to use php array with sql IN operator?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, in-operator

I have and array with two values and I want to use it with sql IN operator in select query.

Here is the structure of my table

```
id comp_id
1   2
2   3
3   1
```

I have an array `$arr` which have two values `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`

I want to fetch the record of comp_id 1 and comp_id 2. So I wrote the following query.

```
SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN ($arr)
```

But it does not return the results.

Comment: Step 1 is to debug your own code. If you printed out the query you were sending to MySQL, you'd see that `SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN (Array)` is not right. Trying to concatenate an array to a string doesn't automatically turn it into a comma separated list of words.

Comment: Step 2 is to search SO to find out how many thousands of times this question has already been answered

Comment: I answered on this problem, it will solve your problem too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition/36070527#36070527

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Since you have plain integers, you can simply join them with commas:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE comp_id IN (" . implode(',', $arr) . ")";
```

If working with with strings, particularly untrusted input:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE comp_id IN ('" 
     . implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $arr)) 
     . "')";
```

Note this does not cope with values such as `NULL` (will be saved as empty string), and will add quotes blindly around numeric values, which does not work if using [strict mysql mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#idm140082377917056).

`mysql_real_escape_string` is the function from the original mysql driver extension, if using a more recent driver like mysqli, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead.

However, if you just want to work with untrusted numbers, you can use `intval` or `floatval` to sanitise the input:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE comp_id IN (" . implode(",", array_map('intval', $arr)) . ")";
```

Comment: I used this method and it works fine but with a warning of `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\x\x\x\xxx.php on line 81`

Comment: @Ahmad Your `$arr` is most likely not an array. Check that you are constructing it properly.

Comment: It will retrieve the same result but its not the best answer, you discovered to SQL Injection attacks, 
I answered on this problem, it will solve your problem too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition/36070527#36070527

Comment: This will only work for numeric values in your array.  If `$arr` contains strings, they will be unquoted after the implode and the database engine will likely not be happy, e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (foo, bar, baz);` is not valid SQL for most databases.

Comment: Well the implication of the question was had numbers, although it wasnt absolutely explicit.

Comment: This should now be updated with mysqli_escape_string() I believe.

Comment: Well yes, if using MySQLi connector use mysqli functions, note its `mysqli_real_escape_string` but will need to pass the $link ident too! Not easy with array_map! So may be easier to use the object orientated style to as callable, `array_map(array($link,'escape_string'), $arr)`

Answer (score 16):

you need to convert the array into comma-separated string:

```
$condition = implode(', ', $arr);
```

And, additionally, you might want to escape the values first (if you are unsure about the input):

```
$condition = implode(', ', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $arr));
```

Comment: Umm, you can't just call mysql_real_escape_string on the data, would still need to add quotes around the values (othrwise creating invalid SQL).

Answer (score 5):

$arr is a php array, to the sql server you need to send a string that will be parsed
you need to turn your array in a list like 1, 2, etc..

to do this you can use the function http://php.net/implode

so before running the query try

```
$arr = implode ( ', ', $arr);
```

Comment: I used this method and it works fine but with a warning of `Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\wamp\www\x\x\x\xxx.php on line 81`

Comment: @Ahmad that's strange.. maybe for a case where you don't have elements in that array or the variable is not initialized yet.. ?

Comment: See my comment above.  This does not work for string values in the array.

Comment: @CXJ sure, you are right, this answers only the case in the question posted by the OP... for strings you would have to quote *and* escape the values

Answer (score 5):

You need to implode your array with ',' comma

```
$imploded_arr = implode(',', $arr);

SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN ($imploded_arr)
```

Answer (score 4):

you can only pass string to mysql as query, so try this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE comp_id IN (".implode(',',$arr).")");
```

Answer (score 4):

All the people here are proposing the same thing but i got a warning in WordPress because of a simple error. **You need to add commas to your imploded string.** To be precise something like this.

```
$query = "SELECT *FROM table Where comp_id IN ( '" . implode( "', '", $sanitized_brands ) . "' )";
```

Hoping it helps someone like me. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing PHP and SQL - for the `IN` SQL operator, you need a format like:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE comp_id IN (1,2)
```

So to get that in PHP you need to do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN (".implode(',',$arr).")"
```

Bear in mind that this only works if the array comprises of integers. You have to escape each element if they are strings.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table where comp_id in (".implode(',',$arr.")";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually convert your `$arr` to a string. The simplest way with what you're doing would be to use `implode()`

```
$query = 'SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN (' . implode(',', $arr) . ')';
```

Right now if you `echo` your query you'll see that rather than the array being in the `IN` statement, it will just be the word "Array"

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the array to a string for use in the query:

```
$list = implode(',', $arr);
```

Then it can be used in the IN clause:

```
SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN ($list)
```

Comment: not working for string values, since with implode you get one string and not separate string values as needed for the sql query

Comment: correct answer is here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072185/formatting-a-php-array-for-an-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 2):

As per @barryhunter 's answer which works only on array that contains integer only:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN (".implode(',',$arr).")";
```

I've made some tweaks to make it work for array of strings:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table Where comp_id IN ('".implode("','",$arr)."')";
```

Comment: clever solution for text string elements! works in Laravel, when using `DB::raw`

Answer (score 0):

There are some risks of SQL injection in a few of the previous answers. It might be fine if you are completely certain about `$arr` being sanitized (and will stay that way). But if you aren't completely sure, you might want to mitigate such risk using `$stmt->bindValue`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
# PHP
$in_list = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $key = 'in_param_' . i;
    $in_list[':' . $key] = array('id' => $arr[$i], 'param' => $key);
}
$keys = implode(', ', array_keys($in_list));

// Your SQL ...
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table where id IN ($keys)";


foreach ($in_list as $item) {
    $stmt->bindValue($item['param'], $item['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
$stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($sql)->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array is of Integers :

```
$searchStringVar = implode(",",$nameIntAryVar);
$query="SELECT * from table NameTbl WHERE idCol='$idVar' AND comp_id IN ($searchStringVar)";
```

If your array is of Strings :

```
$searchStringVar = implode("','",$nameStringAryVar);
$query="SELECT * from table NameTbl WHERE idCol='$idVar' AND comp_id IN ('$searchStringVar')";
```