# Why is my SQL View empty?

Tags: php, sql

I checked in my database and the view is created with the expected structure but it's empty, there are no rows.

```
$view= $connexion->prepare("CREATE VIEW MP1 AS SELECT * FROM occupation_data WHERE onetsoc_code IN (".implode(',',$tupleasup).")");
```

Here what my array look for :

```
$tupleasup= array('19-1041.00','19-1042.00');
```

The only thing "weird" that I used is this : [How to use php array with sql IN operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618277/how-to-use-php-array-with-sql-in-operator)

Thank you

Comment: And how does the view look after the php processing?

Comment: It has the expected structure with all the good columns but it's empty

Comment: any errors? checking for them? which MySQL API are you using to connect with? etc.? seems you've a syntax error and not checking for them. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  on the query if using `mysqli_`. Hard to say if you're using that or PDO `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implode should look like this:

```
$view= $connexion->prepare("CREATE VIEW MP1 AS SELECT * FROM occupation_data WHERE onetsoc_code IN ('".implode("','",$tupleasup)."')");
```

(every item should be wrapped up in quotes)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start and end the single quote '

```
$view= $connexion->prepare("CREATE VIEW MP1 AS SELECT * FROM occupation_data WHERE onetsoc_code IN ('".implode('\',\'',$tupleasup)."')");
```

If you echo your query it will be something like this

```
 CREATE VIEW MP1 AS SELECT * FROM occupation_data WHERE onetsoc_code IN (date1','date2);
```

which is a wrong syntax so i added single quotes to complete your query

Comment: If this answer is appropriate accept the answer. Happy to help you :)