# Use php array as parameter for Postgres IN clause

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, auraphp

I am trying to bind a PHP array as argument for a SQL stmt. I am using auraSQL extended PDO so it looks like this:

```
$php_array = ['first', 'second', 'third']
$db->fetchColumn("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column IN (:php_array), ['php_array' => $php_array])"
```

Is there a way to do that? I cannot find out how. I tried to append the `$php_array` as string separated with commas and wrapped in quotes but that doesn't work.

EDIT: Solution was to use AuraSql function `quote` like so:

```
 $db->fetchColumn("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column IN (".$db->quote($php_array).")";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use php array with sql IN operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618277/how-to-use-php-array-with-sql-in-operator)

Comment: I am a bit confused here regarding the usage. Is the $db an object of ExtendedPdo ? In that case I believe you need to query and get the prepared statement and then calling the `fetchColumn` ? There is no wrapper for the `fetchColumn` itself, so this is expected to fail. See https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql/blob/3.x/src/AbstractExtendedPdo.php and https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql/blob/3.x/src/ExtendedPdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Aura.Sql documentation for `quote()`, here:  https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql/blob/3.x/docs/getting-started.md#array-quoting

The SQL `IN` clause requires a comma-delimited list of values.  The Aura.Sql `quote()` method appears to generate that for you.

You should consider using `perform` method.

https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Sql/blob/3.x/docs/getting-started.md#the-perform-method