# How to update multiple MySQL table entries with different id?

Tags: php, mysql

Please make simple answer :)

```
<?php UPDATE user SET point='$_POST[point]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]; ?>
```

[This is image of my simple design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGzT5.png)

Comment: Instead of image add the table in question.

Comment: There is no simpler than your question

Comment: Put those ids in an array and look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618277/how-to-use-php-array-with-sql-in-operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` to check in a list

```
UPDATE user SET point='$_POST[point]' WHERE id in (<list of ids>);
```