# Select multiple rows from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, select, rows

I have a session that contains an array and that array is filled with id's. What is the best way to select all the rows from a MySQL table that correspond to these id's?

So I need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $_SESSION['ids']
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, since $_SESSION['ids'] is an array.

Comment: You will have to use the `IN()` MySQL syntax and loop through your IDs into the `IN()`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476146/mysql-php-select-where-id-array

Comment: for using IN with an array, you first need to break the string. for find_in_set it would not be necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `IN` SQL operator.
In this case your query will look like

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("' . implode('","', $_SESSION['ids'] . '")';
```

This code will produse a query like following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ("1", "2", "foo");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

```
     SELECT * 
     FROM 
        table
     WHERE 
         find_in_set(id, $_SESSION['ids'])>0
```

Comment: I tried the following to test your method: `$_SESSION['ids'] = array(1,2,3); $db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set(id, $_SESSION['ids'])>0');` It produces an error that I can't fix: Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

Comment: print $_SESSION['ids'] ;
find in set needs it in the form of a quoted string such as "1,2,3,4,5". Make sure you are echoing it in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

HI Try This,

```
 $var = $_SESSION['ids'];

 and then fire your query as

 $sql = SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$var';
```