# php mysql query is not doing sum properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing sum with the below query but it is not giving result properly.

If there are four items and it is showing the result like:
**1.000 2.000 3.000 4.000** and it should be like **10.000**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I don't know where I am mistaken please help.

```
<?php
$order_temp =   mysql_query("select * from temp_cart
where item_id = '".$mitem_idC."'  and ses_mem=113 order by id");

while ($torder = mysql_fetch_array($order_temp)) {
    $prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];
    $qtyT       =   $torder['qty']; 

    $chTP   =   mysql_query("
    select * from temp_choices
    where item_id = '".$prITTC."'
    AND ses_mem = 113
    AND status = 1
    ");
    while($chGET    =   mysql_fetch_array($chTP)){
    $fID    =   $chGET['id'];
    $field  =   $chGET['choice_id'];

    $order_tempCHP      =   mysql_query("
    select sum(price) as total, id, ename, choice_id, item_id, price
    from choice_price
    WHERE
     id IN('$field')
    ");
    while ($torderCP    = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_tempCHP)){

    $totalCH    =   $torderCP['total'];

    $tsl    = $totalCH+($qtyT*$prIDTC);

$altsl  = number_format($tsl, 3, '.', '');
echo $altsl;
    } }

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the data and the expected result? Also only the query without the php around it would be nice

Comment: I only read this for like 10 seconds. Try to let the db engine do the work for you. You are making PHP part of the db engine with the loop. (Read: 100 times slower)

Comment: @Philipp please check i have added image

Comment: @Drew can you help me and give me the edited code?

Comment: Yes I can but I always try to let someone else do it first. Do what @Philipp was talking about (tabular layout with in and out data). And do a `show create table xyz` output for each table `xyz` . Usually the only standing between and an answer is what you are not nicely providing.

Comment: @Drew yes you are right even me i seek help only after when i am failed to do after trying alot

Comment: I don't understand what is so practical about not indenting your code properly. It should be an automatism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to my question above after trying and trying i found the solution and resolved my problem according to below code:

Thanks to @John Kugelman at [MySQL query using an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101662/mysql-query-using-an-array)

```
    $order_temp =   mysql_query("select * from temp_cart
    where item_id = '".$mitem_idC."'  and ses_mem=113 order by id");
    while ($torder = mysql_fetch_array($order_temp)) {
        $prITTD     =   $torder['id'];
        $prITTC     =   $torder['item_id'];

$chTPaa =   mysql_query("
select choice_id
FROM temp_choices
WHERE item_id = '$prITTC'
AND ses_mem = 113
AND status = 1
group by choice_id
");
while ($chGETaa =   mysql_fetch_assoc($chTPaa)){
$temp[] = $chGETaa['choice_id'];
}
$thelist    =   implode(",",$temp);

    $order_tempCHP      =   mysql_query("
    select sum(price) as total
    from choice_price
    WHERE
     id IN ($thelist)
    AND
        item_id = '".$prITTC."'
    ");
    while($torderCP     = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_tempCHP)){
    $totalCH    =   $torderCP['total'];

    $tsl    = $totalCH+($qtyT*$prIDTC);

$altsl  = number_format($tsl, 3, '.', '');
echo $altsl;
    } }
```